# Does enum work only for integer fields in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, enums, rails-models

## This is my model

```
class Setting < ApplicationRecord
  serialize :additional_settings, JSON
  store(:additional_settings,
    accessors: %i[duration_type remind_before],
    coder: JSON)
  enum duration_type: %i[days hours]
end
```

### additional_settings is a JSON column

```
> Setting.duration_types 
> {"days": 0 ,"hours": 1}
```

this works fine

But

```
> a = Setting.first
> #<Setting id: 32, name: "start_date_setting", additional_settings: {"remind_before"=>1, "duration_type"=>1}> 
> a.days?
> false
> a.hours?
> false
```

this doesn't work as expected

and

```
> a.days!
> (0.5ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.8ms)  UPDATE `settings` SET `updated_at` = '2020-05-23 06:09:21', `additional_settings` = '\"{\\\"remind_before\\\":1,\\\"duration_type\\\":\\\"days\\\"}\"' WHERE `settings`.`id` = 32
   (2.0ms)  COMMIT
```

this should actually update duration_type as 0 but its updated as "days"

does this work only for integer fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way to make enum work with string values. You can do it like this:

```rb
enum duration_type: {
  days: "days",
  hours: "hours"
}
```

But it won't help to make the code work in this case. The problem here is that ActiveRecord expects `enum` to be defined on the attribute and stored in the database as a column. It's not compatible with stores.

Here is an implementation of `#days?`: [click](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/f4fe03bf80a6ce9e12a7b5c4f060618f1c31a965/activerecord/lib/active_record/enum.rb#L204). As you can see, Rails is checking `self[attr]`  where `attr` is the name of the enum (`duration_type` in our case). And `self[attr]` is equal to `self.attributes[attr]`. For the model `Setting` attributes contains only `additional_settings`, so no value found, so `self.attributes[:duration_type]` gives `nil`.

There is a question why `a.days!` work without exception in this case then, right? Well, it's tricky. Here is an implementation of this method: [click](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/enum.rb#L208). It's basically a call to `update!(attr => value)` where `attr` is `duration_type` and value is enum's value. Under the hood `update!` calls `assign_attributes` like this: `s.assign_attributes(duration_type: "days")`, - which is equal to `s.duration_type = "days"`. And because attr accessor is defined for `duration_type` (you specified it in `store` call) it writes value to `additional_settings` and saves it.

Here is a test to check how it works:

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

require "bundler/inline"

gemfile(true) do
  source "https://rubygems.org"

  git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

  gem "activerecord", "6.0.3"
  gem "sqlite3"
  gem "byebug"
end

require "active_record"
require "minitest/autorun"
require "logger"

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(adapter: "sqlite3", database: ":memory:")
ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)

ActiveRecord::Schema.define do
  create_table :settings do |t|
    t.text :additional_settings
  end
end

class Setting < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :additional_settings, JSON

  store :additional_settings,
    accessors: %i[duration_type remind_before],
    coder: JSON

  enum duration_type: { days: "days", hours: "hours" }
end

class BugTest < Minitest::Test
  def test_association_stuff
    s = Setting.new
    s.duration_type = :days
    s.save!
    puts s.attributes
  end
end
```